# Find Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am asked to find the coefficients for $f(t)=\sin^{2}(5t)$
$$Period =\frac{\pi}{5}$$

so I wrote $$a_n\cdot\sin(\frac{n\pi{t}}{\frac{\pi}{10}})=\sin^{2}(5t)$$

$$a_n\cdot\sin(10n{t})=\sin^{2}(5t)$$

and I saw I can't go further.

and I wrote a little bit different $\sin^{2}(5t)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(10t)$ , I hope it's right(they have same period),so

$$b_n\cdot\cos(10nt)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(10t)$$

so here I say : $n=1,a_0=\frac12,b_1=-\frac12$

Did I do something wrong ?

I would gladly answer this question myself but wolfram gives : [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20coefficient%20sin%5E2%285x%29)
and I don't understand it :(.

I used this as my formula, where L= Period/2 : 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi/5}\int_0^{\pi/5}\sin^2(5t)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nt}{\pi/5}\right)dt=a_n=\frac{10}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/5}\sin^2(5t)\cos\left(10 nt\right)dt=...$$

$$b_n=\frac{2}{\pi/5}\int_0^{\pi/5}\sin^2(5t)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nt}{\pi/5}\right)dt=a_n=\frac{10}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/5}\sin^2(5t)\sin\left(10 nt\right)dt=...$$

Comment: would there be another way ?

Comment: not really ! It's how Fourier coefficient are defined.

Comment: Is my answer a wrong one ?

Comment: I don't really understand it but it looks like to come from no way.